# How To Use Vector Points in C++ OpenCv?

Tags: c++, opencv

Could you guys Please help me in providing good notes or links ?

For Ex :  I need to create a vector and dump these x,y values in Vector ..

```
Data { X , Y } = {1,1} , {1,2} , {1,3}, {2,1},{2,2},{2,3},{3,1},{3,2},{3,3}
```

Comment: Point: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#point

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A vector of point in OpenCV is just a standard [C++ STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) vector containing [OpenCV Point](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#point) objects :

```
std::vector<Point> data;
data.push_back(Point(1,1));
data.push_back(Point(1,2));
data.push_back(Point(1,3));
data.push_back(Point(2,1));
...
```

Alternatively, if you're using [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) or later you can use a list initialization:

```
std::vector<Point> data = {Point(1,1), Point(1,2), Point(1,3), Point(2,1)};
```

Take a look at the [C++ reference for STL Vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 4):

So... you want to use a vector to store data... wherein each element is a pair of `int`s?  Well, if you don't want to create your own type, use a tuple or pair:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// ...

std::vector<std::pair<int, int> v;
// ...
v.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 1));
// ...
auto p = c[offset];
int x = p.first;
int y = p.second;
```

Comment: I think he probably want to use the opencv Point class instead.

Comment: @zakinster: You "think he probably..."?  The question just shows some pseudo code, but I guess "Point" is in the title.  I suppose it would be extremely difficult to reason out how to change the vector template type.

Comment: @zakinster: Yeah, I figured you weren't

Comment: I don't know why you guys down voted my question, and only if some one doesn't know the how to approach the problem or don't know how to start off, are coming here to post the questions ..its weird :(

Comment: @Pixel: Well, I didn't downvote, but it's probably because the question is a bit vague (notice how I thought you wanted to store pairs of ints) and you didn't try anything first.  We want to see a good faith effort.  Surely there exist endless examples, easily found, which explain how to use a vector.